# Редактор HTML5

Tags: html, html5, редактор

Доброго времени суток.

Недавно был на конференции, посвященной HTML5 и увидел интерфейс редактора, который сам дополнял коды, тэги. Очень понравилось. Название, к сожалению,не разглядел.

Кто может просто посоветовать хорошие редакторы с автодополнением и прочих облегчающих фич?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Самый лучший редактор всегда платный, так что imho лучше всего использовать:

- JetBrains [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) для `HTML CSS JavaScript`

P.S WebStorm разбирает код всех подключённых файлов так что бы можете подключать хоть что лишь бы без eval'a а ещё у него есть отладчик WebStormDebugger для eval'a и не только...

Answer (score 6):

Лучшее решение Sublime Text 2, если Вам нужен редактор HTML5, CSS, JavaScript (и еще десяток языков программирования), а если именно мощное средство разработки IDE, то тут могу посоветовать только PHPShtorm.

Answer (score 4):

Мне очень нравится phpDesigner 8. Посмотрите, может приглянется.

Comment: PHP Desinger 8 мне понравился.

Comment: Реально крутой редктор! Кроме всего, автодополнение для js, php ...

Answer (score 2):

если вы пишите на .net то установив resharper, поддержка будет встроена  http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

php  - http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

ну т.д. посмотрите на http://www.jetbrains.com/
просто чтоб все в одном редакторе и не танцевать с двумя